# Cloud init cannot raise network interfaces in Ubuntu 16.04 with Static IP Configuration

Tags: linux, qemu, cloud-init

I have been experimenting with cloud-init and qemu.  This is how I start my VM:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  --enable-kvm \
  -nographic \
  -m 2G -smp 4 \
   -drive file=/disks/mustafa.img,if=virtio \
   -cdrom /disks/my-seed.img \
   -device virtio-net,netdev=network0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01 \
   -netdev tap,id=network0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no
```

And the respecting meta-data and user-data files are:

```
instance-id: 49380625-37c5-48b0-8a2b-60bd1392519a
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    interface0:
       match:
           macaddress: 52:55:00:D1:55:01
       set-name: eth0
       addresses:
       - 172.17.0.2/255.255.0.0
       gateway4: 172.17.0.1
```

This is the user data, not really related but whatever.

```
#cloud-config
password: passw0rd
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
```

But it hangs with the following output:

```
[  OK  ] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[    6.148261] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[    6.168261] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[    6.188260] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  OK  ] Started Set console font and keymap.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    6.044744] cloud-init[417]: Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 running 'init-local' at Sat, 13 May 2017 14:49:10 +0000. Up 5.67 seconds.
[  OK  ] Started Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking).
[  OK  ] Reached target Network (Pre).
[  OK  ] Started LSB: AppArmor initialization.
         Starting Raise network interfaces...
[ ***  ] A start job is running for Raise ne... interfaces (2min 25s / 5min 1s)
```

What am I doing wrong? I have read https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config-format-v2.html

By the way, the following works perfectly:

```
instance-id: 49380625-37c5-48b0-8a2b-60bd1392519a
network-interfaces: |
  auto ens3
  iface ens3 inet static
  address 172.17.0.2
  netmask 255.255.0.0
  gateway 172.17.0.1
```

But I do not want to use static interface names, and make them match hosts.

Comment: I have the same problem with Debian 10 buster on Proxmox :(